# img is not a numerical tuple

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, opticalflow

The whole program is to visualize the extracted optical flows from each image from one folder. The problem happens when I applied draw_flow function. I've converted the image array into a tuple, but it is not a numerical tuple as the error mentions. I don't know how to fix this. 
 When I was trying to execute the code as the following:

```
def draw_flow(im, greyim, flow, step = 16):

    h, w = im.shape[:2]
    y, x = np.mgrid[step/2:h:step,step/2:w:step].reshape(2, -1)
    fx, fy = flow[y,x].T
    lines = np.vstack([x, y, x+fx, y+fy]).T.reshape(-1,2,2)
    lines = np.int32(lines)

    for(x1,y1),(x2,y2) in lines:
        cv2.line(greyim, (x1,y1), 1, (0,255,0), -1)
    return greyim


def main():
    mypath = 'jpl_thomas'
    onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) ]
    color_images = np.empty(len(onlyfiles), dtype=object)
    gray_images = np.empty(len(onlyfiles), dtype=object)

    for n in range(1, len(onlyfiles)):
        color_images[n] = cv2.imread(join(mypath,onlyfiles[n]))

        gray_images[n] = cv2.imread(join(mypath,onlyfiles[n]),0)

    for i in range(2, len(gray_images)):
        flow =cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(gray_images[i],gray_images[i-1], None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)
        draw_flow(color_images[i],tuple(gray_images[i]),flow, step = 16)
```

I got the error message like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.python", line 51, in <module>
  main()
File "main.python", line 45, in main
  draw_flow(color_images[i],tuple(gray_images[i]),flow, step = 16)
File "main.python", line 19, in draw_flow
  cv2.line(greyim, (x1,y1), 1, (0,255,0), -1)
TypeError: img is not a numerical tuple
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to pass `gray_images[i]` as a tuple ? Because, this works just fine without converting to tuple on my machine.

I am guessing you have modified this line for intermediate testing, because it is not correct.

```
cv2.line(greyim, (x1,y1), 1, (0,255,0), -1)
```

As per the docs,

```
cv.Line(img, pt1, pt2, color, thickness=1, lineType=8, shift=0)
```

`pt2` is a point passed as tuple and `thickness` needs to be a non-negative number.